# Не получается запустить проект

Tags: java, android, test-automation

Осваиваю UIAutomator с помощью вот [этого](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/automatic-android-testing-with-uiautomator) туториала, там объясняется как создать и запустить этот проект в `Eclipse` пытаюсь создать его в `Android Studio`, но не получается.
Там написано Если вы используете `Eclipse*`:

Создайте новый `Java-проект в Eclipse`. Клик правой кнопкой на вашем проекте в `Project Explorer` и затем клик на `Properties`.
В `Properties` выберите `Java Build Path`  и добавьте требуемые библиотеки:

Если вы пользуетесь иной средой разработки, убедитесь что файлы android.jar и uiautomator.jar добавлены в настройки проекта.

Если я правильно понял, то в моем случае их надо добавить в `dependencies`, я добавляю их, потом создаю класс как там написано, но почему-то все подчеркивается красным не видит библиотеки, как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.jar разной версии бывает, убедитесь какая именно нужна или же нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по проекту в самом конце списка будет properites или prefernce, потом в новом списке найдите android и клацайте по ней. Там покажет в правой части список версиий API android, выберите нужную, т.е. максимальную API, с которой будите работать. А вот uiautomatir.jar нужно не в dependencies вставлять, а в папку libs. Ну и рефреш нажмите, если автоматом после изменения не обновляется, чтобы в workspace еще добавил библиотеку.

Надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны добавить ваши jar файлы в папку libs[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я делал это тоже не помогло, не знаю что не так делаю, замучился

Comment: @java На какой минимальной SDK вы пытаетесь это все запустить?

Comment: я запускаю на SDK 18